# Implementing Java2SAutoTextField to a JtextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

1) I was able to add a `JTextField` to the `JFrame`, and I initialized the class [`Java2sAutoTextField`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm) as given in Auto Complete `JTextField` (Swing / AWT / SWT / JFace forum at JavaRanch).

2) I initialized the list and field inside the `JFrame` constructor, as shown below.

```
List possible = new ArrayList(); 
possible.add("Austria"); 
possible.add("Italy"); 
possible.add("Croatia"); 
possible.add("Hungary"); 
Java2sAutoTextField autoCompleter = new Java2sAutoTextField(possible);
```

3) The problem that arises is this: Even though I have initialized the `Java2sAutoTextField`, how can I apply auto completing to the `JTextField`?

Comment: Reformatted code & edited content; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: you may also wanna have a look on this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460911/java-swing-display-search-result-in-a-popup-under-jtextfield-like-facebook-searc I haven't share the class yet, but it'll be soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `main()` method below to [`Java2sAutoTextField`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/AutocompleteTextField.htm) produced the expected result after typing "H". It's not crucial for this example, but Swing GUIs should be constructed on the [EDT](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
                "Austria", "Croatia", "Hungary", "Italy"));
            JFrame f = new JFrame("AutoTest");
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.add(new Java2sAutoTextField(list));
            f.pack();
            f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            f.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that `Java2sAutoTextField` _is_ a `JTextField`.

Comment: Is it possible to download a JAR file that contains the code for this ? I guess the Java2s guys also have an auto complete combo box. I would love to add that JAR to my project library in Eclipse :)