# How can I ignore any KeyListeners that may have been added by client programs when certain conditions are met?

Tags: java, events, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I haven't had any luck with the web as far as this is concerned, the closest I've come is to read up on the `EventQueue`, but I can't seem to find a way remove an event by default.

I've overloaded a `JTextField` so that it displays the remaining characters in a "guessed" word (part of an auto complete component) and when "Enter" is pressed while the `JTextField` is still "guessing" a word I want it to fill in the remaining portion of the word (`this.setText(this.currentGuess);`) and ignore any other `KeyListeners` that may have been added to the component in a client program.

As a test, in the constructor I'm adding two `KeyListeners` and so far nothing I've done has managed to prevent the second from firing.

Comment: Oh you've got relevant code? Well why didn't you include it!!!!!

Comment: @Shakedown I didn't see any of my code as relevant to the question since nothing that I had done worked and I found out on my own before posting why said attempts failed. I can't think of any snippet that was relevant and if I failed on that part, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`getKeyListeners()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getKeyListeners%28%29) to see who's listening and remove all but your desired listener.

Addendum: Also consider alternate implementations, such as the one discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675046).

Comment: I thought I saw somewhere that wasn't really a good way to do it, of course I would want to add them back when I'm done with what I need to do otherwise any the client program would have added would be lost?

Comment: @izuriel: It's not ideal, and you'd want to document the behavior. I'd look at alternatives; I cited a recent one above.